# What's the longest monosyllabic word? And disyllabic?

Tags: syllables

Another question on the site made me take notice that *through* is monosyllabic, but quite long. Are there longer monosyllabic words? What's the longest disyllabic word in English?

**Edit:** so, Wikipedia has a page for monosyllabic words, but none for disyllabic ones. Anyone can think of any long disyllabic example?

Comment: measured how? vocally, orthographically?

Comment: @bmargulies: orthographically

Comment: I've seen lots on monosyllabic words, but nothing ever on disyllabic ones.

Comment: I'm guessing we aren't allowed to suggest, *Aaaaaarrrrrrrrrggggghhhhhhh!*

Comment: Defining syllables orthographically does not really make any sense, but I guess we can assume the intended definition is “containing only one/two vowel(s)/vowel combination(s)”. If we define instead by phonetic syllables (and include proper names), the longest disyllabic word I can think of is the surname ***Featherstonehaugh*** (pronounced /ˈfænʃɔː/, for no apparent reason other than English aristocracy).

Comment: I presume that F'x meant to define syllables phonetically, but length orthographically.

Comment: To quote my childhood: *What is the longest word in the English language? ... It is **smiles**. There is a mile between each  "s"!*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_English#Words_with_certain_characteristics_of_notable_length):

> - **Strengths** is the longest word in the English language containing only one vowel.
> - **Rhythms** is the longest word in the English language containing none of the five recognised vowels.
> - **Schmaltzed** and **strengthed** appear to be the longest monosyllabic words recorded in OED; but if **squirrelled** is pronounced as one syllable only (as permitted in SOED for *squirrel*), it is the longest.

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_longest_English_words_with_one_syllable) suggests that *schtroumpfed* is the longest; however, it's really a stretch to say this is an English word in any even remotely established sense (and I am definitely not strict in the words I would consider to be "part of" a language).

Answer (score 14):

*Strengths* is a nine-lettered monosyllable. And it is compulsory to mention that *smiles* has one mile between the two S's...

Comment: THWACK! (but +1 anyway)

Answer (score 6):

http://braingle.com/news/hallfame.php?path=language/english/pronunciation/syllable.p&sol=1
gives "scratchbrushed" (14 letters) as the longest 2-syllable word. A more common word is "breakthroughs" (13 letters).

If you allow hyphens, perhaps "straight-stretched" (17 letters) is acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

Scraunched Scroonched Strengthed

Comment: Despite your unembellished brevity, I think you may actually be on to something there.  Alas, *schmaltzed* *given separately) ties you.  But these are all of the same form of a liquid *s* (possibly palatalized) following by an optional stop and then a nasal or liquid, and finally given an *-ed* suffix. One might make something of that.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia's list includes the 11-letter "broughammed," which means to be taken by brougham, a type of carriage. Its meaning is similar to that of "bused" or "carted."

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't allow hyphens for disyllabic words, the London street name *Knightsbridge* is 13 letters. (It is also one of the rare words with six consonants in a row.)

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia has a nice list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_longest_English_words_with_one_syllable).  *Schmaltzed* is probably the longest "real word", being in the OED, but it depends on what you consider standard / reputable.

I'm not sure about disyllabic words.

Comment: Did you just equate “real word” and “being in the OED”?  Courageous.

Comment: @tchrist See the quotes and the caveat that follows?

Answer (score 1):

*Strengths* ties with **twelfths** for the longest word in the English language containing only one vowel.  Although, in view of my contributions elsewhere

[Is a syllable defined phonetically or etymologically?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224760/is-a-syllable-defined-phonetically-or-etymologically)

I have to say I'm not sure I can happily call it a monosyllable ("two elfs").