# Is a syllable defined phonetically or etymologically?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, phonology, syllables

Reading recent postings about syllables I've been struck and baffled by talk of the possibility that words may have a different number of syllables when they are written than when they are spoken.

[Is "church" one syllable or two?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224751/is-church-one-syllable-or-two)

[How many syllables are in the word 'hour'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80224/how-many-syllables-are-in-the-word-hour)

As a musician I am very clear that a book of music is just that, a book containing a (more or less helpful) representation of music.  The book itself is not a piece of music (any more than Magritte's *painting* of a pipe 'is' actually a pipe).  Only the *sound* of music is music.  It is also my view (and among musicians I'm not out on any kind of limb!) that wonderful and awe-inspiring as music theory is to me, it is based on the work of a succession of rule-breaking composers.  Music theory has always, and can only, play catch-up with music practice.

Do you think this is the case with language ? When I say *church* I make two clear sounds. I think you have to. On what grounds could church be said to have only one syllable ?

The OED offers that syllable is

> a vocal sound or set of sounds uttered with a single effort of articulation and forming a word or an element of a word; each of the elements of spoken language comprising a sound of greater sonority (vowel or vowel-equivalent) with or without one or more sounds of less sonority (consonants or consonant-equivalents).

If I say, "I'll meet you at the church" - *church* involves, for me, two 'efforts of articulation' ... two syllables?

Comment: It only has one vowel. Two syllables requires two distinct vowel sounds.

Comment: Syllables are defined by how the language is spoken.  What precisely a syllable is in something like "church", though, is hard to define, and there can be legitimate disagreement -- different people will have different criteria.  Much easier to agree with a word like "composer" or "temporary".  (Your analogy to music is excellent, by the way.)

Comment: This looks more like a question for [the Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) stack.

Comment: It's certainly not defined etymologically. Etymology is the province of roots. Most would say the English word _nest_ has one syllable, but it has two roots: [*en- 'in'](http://web.archive.org/web/20080630025344/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE127.html), and [*sed- 'sit'](http://web.archive.org/web/20080630025344/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE127.html). Syllables are best exemplified either with an oscilloscope or as a "chest pulse", as Pike used to call it. They do vary from language to language, as do morae and syllable weights.

Comment: A syllable is a beat -- it's a rhythmic notion.  I can say "church" with two syllables, if I try: chur-chsh. Think of the sound of a steam-engine train starting up: chur-chshshsh, chur-chshsh, chur-chsh (going faster).  There's nothing to say that a syllable has to have a vowel.  American Indian languages of the northwest are notorious for having syllables without vowels.  But the thing is, I don't say the English word "church" with two syllables.  I could, but I don't, when I'm speaking normal English.

Comment: @John Not _*en-_ ‘in’, but _*ni-_ ‘down’ (see III.2 in the _*sed-_ article you linked to).

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/syllable

Comment: @GregLee You **can** say "church" with two syllables, or three (/chu'|rr|ch(ə)/) if you please :P though neither would be the "normal" pronunciation /CHərCH/ http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/church 
 
/

Comment: @Hot Licks: I don't really think it's "easy to agree" how many syllables are in a word like ***temporary***. In practice I and many other speakers would almost always deliver that as a two-syllable word. Note that [oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/temporary) puts the (optional) middle syllable in brackets in their phonetic representation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- Well, I suppose it's your right to mispronounce "temporary" (;)), but that just goes to show that much of this stuff is hard to define.  Probably best to not overemphasize syllables, period, vs worrying about which one to put the emphasis on.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: we're getting off-topic, but the two-syllable pronunciation of *temporary* sounds very British to me. In *temporary, military*, and so forth, Americans put secondary stress on the *ar* syllable.  Americans pronounce *temporary* with either three (*temprary*) or four syllables

Comment: @Dan: but I bet you say *"the church is by the lake"* with 6 syllables and not 7. It's only when *"church"* is the last word in a phrase that you can possibly think of giving it two syllables. That's why it should count as a one-syllable word.

Comment: How about *militarily* ;)

Comment: @Hot Licks: And I suppose it's your right to designate my speech as "mispronunciation", even though it's obviously a bit of a cheek. My understanding is that professional linguists using sophisticated analytical tools are well aware that an awful lot of people *think* they're enunciating things that correspond to the written form, where in actual fact they often *don't*.

Comment: Sure @Peter Shor, 'The chur chis by the lake' ;)

Comment: When I talk proper I say 'The chur ch is by the lake'.

Comment: @Dan: How about *"The church stands by the lake."* I still think that's 6 syllables. Is that *"The chur chstands by the lake"*?

Comment: @PeterShor not sure I can even say this one

Comment: Ok I can say it @PeterShor, but the second 'ch' is swallowed and 'improperly' silent.  If I were saying it formally I would say 'The chur ch stands by the lake'.

Comment: @Dan: I don't believe I have ever heard anybody use two syllables for *church* in the middle of a phrase, as in *"The chur ch stands by the lake."* But I agree that most people probably reduce some of the consonants in the "*rchst*".

Comment: Hmm, you possible need to watch more early British movies ;). I don't think I'm supporting *that* way of speaking.  It's just that the second 'ch' creates a 'swing' feel to the whole.  If you change 'by' for 'beside' it would scan, for me, as ti-tum ti-tum ti-tum ti-tum.  Clearly the second 'ch' is not an emphasised syllable, but as important as any of the other '*ti*'s in the line (i.e. the, be-, and the).

Comment: As for "church", I stand firmly in the middle.  Could be one syllable or two, depending on who's talking, who's listening, and the context.

Comment: Fascinating question but I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be re-asked at http://linguistics.stackexchange.com (too old to migrate). There is nothing particular here about English.

Comment: Short answer: etymology is just history, where the pieces came from. syllables is just pronunciation, how many distinct vowels are involved. Sometimes these result in the same number, sometimes not.

Comment: @Mitch It's not just a question of the number of syllables. Take "despicable" for example. To me the 1st syllable is "des" and the 2nd is "pic," but at least in the US most people say "de" "spic." Someone might convince you that the etymology suggests the s should be on one side or the other, but as you say syllables are just a matter of pronunciation and people are going to pronounce words as they wish. So I say etymology influences, but does not dictate, pronunciation.P.S I hope you don't succeed in closing this "fascinating question." It pertains to ELU and I wouldn't see it elsewhere.

Comment: @Mitch Whether pronunciation is on-topic has been [considered in Meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/277/142322) and pronounced *on-topic* by a vote of 19 to 2. I like this question and would be interested to see a well-researched answer. Would you reconsider your vote to close?

Comment: @GregLee - You comment that you "...don't say the English word "church" with two syllables ... when... speaking normal English".  You also say that you can, if you try, say "church" with two syllables - *chur-chsh*.  Isn't *chur-chsh* precisely how you say church when it finishes a sentence?  For example, *Where's the vicar?  She's in the church."

Comment: @Lawrence pronunciation _of English_ is entirely on-topic here. This question is not specific to English. I'm being a bit legalistic here. If people have substantive answers for here sure go ahead, it's not lacking use to inform English enthusiasts of general linguistic concepts through English examples.

Comment: @Airymouse Of course etymology and syllabification are related. But how they are related is not an English specific discussion.

Comment: No one has suggested a look at the definition of syllable?

Comment: @Mitch - just been looking (again!).  Not terribly helpful on Wiki ("A syllable is a unit of organization").

Comment: @Mitch [Hmm](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224760/is-a-syllable-defined-phonetically-or-etymologically?noredirect=1#comment871689_224760), already [linked](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224760/is-a-syllable-defined-phonetically-or-etymologically?noredirect=1#comment479713_224760). Here it is anyway - [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/syllable): "A unit of pronunciation having one vowel sound, with or without surrounding consonants, forming the whole or a part of a word; for example, there are two syllables in water and three in inferno." ...

Comment: ... Seems consistent with the tenor of the discussion above. If we may include the surrounding "ch" consonant sounds, I suppose it would be fair to close the question on the basis of lack of research. On the other hand, if we focus on *or without surrounding sounds* in the definition, we're back to square one. :)

Comment: @Lawrence to that point, this question would certainly be genref on linguistics.

Comment: @Dan, No, "church" at the end of a sentence, for me, still has just one syllable.  The [t] part of the final affricate can change to a glottal stop in my speech, and that happens only to syllable offset [t].  So this [t] must not begin a syllable.

Comment: Confusion between syllables in a dictionary with syllables in speech. Spoken and written language are not the same.

Comment: @Lambie - and spoken language has to be paramount!

Comment: Yes, of course, speaking came first but a dictionary usually shows only standard ("congealed") pronunciations whereas accents (regional or national) may change the way you personally divide up the syllables.  Though some dictionaries give have several syllabifications.

Comment: Syllables are some of the most weakly-defined and contentious subjects in phonetics and phonology. Many languages have differences between phonetic and phonological syllables, and in writing, the term has an altogether different meaning related to hyphenation. I think it's safe to say that in speech, syllables are defined by _sound_ (not necessarily phonetics, but sound), never etymology; but in writing, by a combination of sound, etymology, and aesthetics. Beyond that, it's too tangly a web to hack away at here, I fear.

Comment: A rule of thumb I was taught was to clap your hands as you spoke.  If it fits into the single handclap, it's a syllable.  Church = one syllable.  Hour = one syllable.  Not sure how you're getting two syllables out of church - there's no significant change of sound in it.

Comment: @Tim - it's a good rule of thumb to my mind.  "*Chur-ch*" clearly overspills a single clap when I say it.  How do YOU say church - without the final '*ch*'?

Comment: @Dan - Why would I leave off the final 'ch'?  Church by all definitions (including dictionary) has only a single syllable.  You musicians and your extension of vowels :-)

Comment: @Dan - but does it make it to a second clap?

Answer (score 1):

Not all English speakers pronounce all words with the same number of syllables.
However there are general agreements as to how many syllables any word has. This is certainly true in singing.

In traditional music,  one syllable will be sung on one note. Of course, if there are more syllables than notes, one "cheats" and adds  notes. More  notes than syllables, then one can "cheat: by distorting the word to created new syllables. Many songs have an even syllable to note equation. The "cheating" usually happens when there is an attempt to fit too many or too few words to an established tune,
In the well known song "Mary Had a Little Lamb", there are exactly the same number of syllables as notes in the tune. I have never noted any problems with this song as to syllabification.
Often persons who are not native speakers of English and speak English with an "accent" exhibit no such "accent" when singing English songs. Native and non-native speakers follow the same syllables with the same stress dictated by the tune.  If one wished to assure the convention as to number of syllables is followed, one could do worse than to practice singing single syllable words on a single note

Almost always, the number of syllables in an English word is determined by the number of sounds (vowels) in the word; not the number of written vowels, but the number of distinct vowel sounds.

> lit-tle

The second vowel in "little" is not written. Tl could not be pronounced without the understood vowel.
Etymology would have little to do with syllabification, unless one were trying to pronounce a current English word in the manner of some previous era. That does not occur very often.
I'm not sure this is a very serious issue for the most part. Probably few care if a syllable is added or subtracted in speaking as long as the meaning of the word is clear. Unless one is singing.

Comment: Very interesting.  From a singing perspective the final '*ch*' of church is rarely (never?) sung.  If '*church*' is the final word of a phrase then the final '*ch*' is added without an extra note.  If '*church*' is followed by another word the final '*ch*' is usually swallowed or elided.

Comment: I had not wished to get into "church". I can touch my diaphragm with a hand, and feel only ONE motion as I say church, repeatedly. I only pronounce the one syllable. I cannot even imagine hearing "Church": pronounced.with more than one syllable.If I had to imagine it, it would probably be "chu-urch".. It may be easier for me to unfailingly pronounce a single syllable, as I pronounce the word "Cherch", like "perch".  Without hearing how you say or have heard "Church", I am in the Twilight Zone as to how to relate.

Comment: There is probably an unrelated "sound" after pronouncing "Church" that is a result of the release of the vocal mechanism, a  "sound" that is not part of the word, That is because the mouth is resetting in anticipation of the nest task.. Air might still be flowing through the mouth and a slight whisper could result..

Comment: Fascinating.  If I clap when I say 'church', the sound I am making after the clap is made by my mouth not my diaphragm.  It is, however, integral to my speaking of the word and not any kind of buccal 'resetting'!

Comment: Try closing your mouth after saying "Church",------ immediately after.

Comment: I get 'chur-chuh' (the final schwa is minimal ...but there).

Comment: I put a hand over my mouth in addition to closing it, and I felt air coming through the nose. But, I could not say it was a sound. We really need a recording. The computer says it is time for us to stop.

Answer (score 1):

Syllables are only related to speaking. A syllable is determined by a vowel pronunciation. In the U.S., secretary is a four syllable word. In the U.K., it is usually only three syllables. Writing does not determine syllables. One's pronunciation or the pronunciation indicators in a dictionay determine syllables. As to "hour", it is a diphthong in southern U.S. (two vowel sounds gliding together in one syllable), but is two distinct syllables in the U.S. North, like ow-wer". Same goes for fire and oil. Church is very clearly one syllable, since it has only one vowel pronounced, unless you know of a locale where it is pronounced "chur-chah".

Sounds made without any vowel, such as "Whewww!" for relief of danger, are not words and have no vowel sounds. Shouting "Arghh" like a pirate could be considered a word with one syllable.

Words in a song are not nearly as exact as one might think. "A-may-zee-ing-grace" is sung as five distinct tones, but if one spoke this phrase in conversation, it would be only four syllables. In "Angels We Have Heard on High", the word "Gloria" is sung with many syllables or tones. Spoken, it is only three... unless a dialect pronounces it as "glor-yah". Then the second syllable is a diphthong. Many languages have diphthongs. In Mandarin Chinese, there are dozens, such as "tian" for sky / heaven / day or "guo" for a melon-like fruit. If you pronounced tian as two syllables like "tee-ann", most Chinese would not understand you. Same for guo pronounced like "Goo-wah".

Comment: If that title "Angels We Have Heard on High" is unfamiliar to readers, they might instead know "Angels from the Realms of Glory". In its refrain, the word Gloria is sung to many successive *pitches*. The notation in which they'd be written would need many *notes* to represent them. *Tones* don't come into it, and although the [ɔ:] sound is sung for a long time to many pitches, the [glɔ:] is still only one *syllable*.